# Perform function on entire column based on 2 row conditions on nested list using tidyverse / purrr::map

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to perform a function or `mutate` a column in a nested list of dataframes based on the condition of two row values. Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

dlist <- data_frame(group = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 name = c("a","b","c","a","b","c"),
                 val = c(5,4,3,3,2,1)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest()
```

That results in:

```
 dlist[[2]]

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name    val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         5
2 b         4
3 c         3

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name    val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         3
2 b         2
3 c         1
```

In this case I would like to perform `mutate(val = val*5)` if the conditions `name == a` & `val > 4` are met so that **every row** in `val` in `dlist[[2]][1]` would be multiplied by 5, but `dlist[[2]][2]` would remain unchanged. The outcome would look like this:

```
 dlist[[2]]

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name    val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         25
2 b         20
3 c         15

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name    val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         3
2 b         2
3 c         1
```

I have been going over `if_else` and `case_when` for hours now, and I can't figure out how to multiply on the entire column and not just the row where the two conditions match. I keep ending up with this:

```
dlist[[2]][1]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name    val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 a         25
2 b         4
3 c         3
```

Maybe I am not using the correct search terms. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution based in the tidyverse could look as follows. Please note that I ungrouped the data frame from your example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dlist <- dlist %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ mutate(., check = if_else(name == 'a' & val > 4, TRUE, FALSE))),
         data = map(data, ~ mutate(., check = if_else(TRUE %in% check, TRUE, FALSE))),
         data = map(data, ~ mutate(., val = if_else(check == TRUE, val*5, val))),
         data = map(data, ~ select(., -check)))

dlist[[2]]

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   name    val
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a        25
# 2 b        20
# 3 c        15

# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   name    val
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a         3
# 2 b         2
# 3 c         1
```

**Data**

```
dlist <- structure(list(group = c(1, 2), data = list(structure(list(name = c("a", 
"b", "c"), val = c(5, 4, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(name = c("a", "b", 
"c"), val = c(3, 2, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L)))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Good trick using T and F to create a separate `check` set. `@rjen` I'm curious why you mentioned ungrouping the data. It didn't appear to make a difference in my reprex here or in my empirical data set.

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you @jnat. If grouping isn't needed, I ungroup right away. In my comment, I was trying to suggest that doing so is usually a good idea. But I could definitely have been more explicit.